# Using cpt and pass a variable using url

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, wp-rewrite

I want to create a nice readable permalink structure for my custom post type (CPT). My CPT "movie" has the following rewrite-slug `movie/movie_name"` (all works fine).

Now i want to add `arg` like this: `movie/movie_name/arg` and use arg in my template file as a php variable.
But obvious it lead to not-found-page. How can i achieve this target?

**edit:** i want it in **FRIENDLY URL** format, it means i dont want to use GET for this.

Answer (score 1):

You may pass it like `movie/movie_name?movie_arg=movie_value`. It is will be available with `$_GET['movie_arg']`. Of course your need extra sanitization to handle this data.

To be able to read this in a WordPress way add params to a `query_vars` filter

```
function add_movie_arg_to_query_vars( $qvars ) {
    $qvars[] = 'movie_arg';
    return $qvars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_movie_arg_to_query_vars' );
```

**Note:** it should not be same as reserved [WordPress query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#parameters) parameters

This way it will be available at your template with `get_query_var('movie_arg')`

```
print_r( get_query_var('movie_arg') ) // movie_value
```

More information [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/#custom-query-vars)

Comment: I must have it in FRIENDLY URL format, it means i dont want to use GET for this.

Comment: Use Query Vars. it is basically a friendly rewrite of $_GET. In Ihar's example, your URL will be something like /movie/movie_name/movie_arg/your_arg

Comment: @SahriarSaikat i tried Query Vars, it didnt work.

Comment: @dede what did not work exactly? provide more details. Is there any PHP error or anything?